# How to parallelize this while statement?

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials, parallelization

I have the following calculation

`k = 1; While[! (PolynomialMod[x^k - 1, poly , Modulus -> 2] === 0), k++]; k`

where poly is a given polynomial. If the polynomial is simple, the calculation is done in under a second, so no problem at all.

However, if we use `poly = 1 + x + x^2 + x^15 + x^16 + x^17 + x^18`, then the calculation takes roughly 7 seconds in my machine. This is just an example of the problem. In reality, I want to calculate the `k`'s for much harder polynomials, where the calculation takes hours (`k` being of order $10^6-10^8$).

The question: is there a way to parallelize this expression? For example, running this on a cluster with 40-50 kernels would speed up the calculations significantly (assuming that an efficient parallelization exists in the first place...). Furthermore, each kernel wouldn't need much allocated memory since each calculation is simple.

---

(Maybe some helpful information...)

We know a hard limit for `k`; it can't be bigger than `order = 2^Exponent[poly, x] - 1`.
However, the issue here is that most of the times `k` is orders of magnitude smaller than `order` and it is not efficient at all to check all numbers till `order` and then find the first one being zero, for example, with a `Table` construction...

Comment: Consider evenly distributing starting $k$ values across the range of interest and accept the first successful response?

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking about something similar, but I am not sure how to write this code efficiently...

Comment: `ParallelTry` is the built-in infrastructure for it, so encapsulate the problem in a function which can be distributed to parallel kernels and use that. I haven't done it myself though, so I'm not planning to write up an answer for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I didn't know of ParallelTry!!

Comment: so, I managed to get it work. However the results are pretty disappointing...First of all, I think the solution that you were refering to, @eyorble, is something like this ```ParallelTry[
 If[PolynomialMod[x^# - 1, poly, 
     Modulus -> 2] === 0, #, $Failed] &, Range[1, order]]```. However, if ```order``` is bigger than $2^{11}-2^{12}$ my laptop crashes. The problem persists even to small sizes (the serial method is faster...). At the same time, I get a solution (inefficient, but still, it works...) with the serial method. Is there a way to optimize the parallelized version more?

Comment: Generating the full input order will use all of the RAM available on most devices. You'd want to send out parallel searches starting from some initial values, not try to search the whole space at once. I wasn't able to get it to go faster myself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
kernelFunction[poly_][{kstart_,kstop_}] := Catch[Do[
   If[PolynomialMod[x^k-1,poly,Modulus->2]===0,Throw[k]],
   {k,kstart,kstop}];Infinity];
DistributeDefinitions[kernelFunction];

try[poly_,imax_:Infinity,batchsize_:100] := With[{kstep=$KernelCount},
  Catch[Do[Min[ParallelMap[kernelFunction[poly],
    batchsize*((i-1)*kstep+Range[0,kstep])+1//Transpose[{Most[#],Rest[#]-1}]&,
    DistributedContexts->None]]//If[#<Infinity,Throw[#]]&,{i,1,imax}];
  Infinity]];
```

Timing:

```
poly = 1+x+x^2+x^15+x^16+x^17+x^18;

(* serial *)
kernelFunction[poly][{1,Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.88467, 9709} *)

(* parallel *)
LaunchKernels[];
try[poly] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.0087, 9709} *)
```

where my `$KernelCount` was $8$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!! After I did some extensive testing, I think that your code works really really well...My only concern is your last remark. So, there is a chance that I have maximum values up to $10^10$ for example and the code chooses randomly to run the value I want last. This would crash the universe...Is this a real possibility? From my testing I didn't encounter any problem like that though...

Comment: values up to $10^{10}$, I meant...

Comment: Updated. This new version should not have the issue mentioned in the first version. But it is also more complicated now, hence more likely to contain errors, please check yourself.

Comment: I tried these two polynomials: $1 + x^7 + x^{10} - x^{11} + x^{13} - x^{14} + x^{15} + x^{16} - x^{17} + x^{18} - x^{20} + x^{21} + x^{24}$ and $1 + x^7 + x^8 + x^{15} + x^{16} + x^{23} + x^{24}$. With both of them I saw a slow down compared to the new ```kernelFunction``` (some timings compared to serial and some times were worse up to 2 times)

Comment: I tried both, and both are faster using the parallel code: from 9 seconds down to 2 seconds in the first case, from 14 down to 3 in the second case. You probably made some mistake, such as not clearing old definitions... Btw, also the people who mainly ask questions on this site should think of themselves as contributors, not merely consumers. You could do more than just say that it does not work.

Comment: My increase is not that radical (less impressive than your previous function somehow), but this, I guess, is mainly due to hardware...I think you are right! Thanks a lot for the parallelization! I think at a cluster, it will be awfully better!!

Comment: Maybe you could just append the previous functions for later use if anyone finds them more performant...:)

Comment: Update: somehow, after a restart now I got from 20sec to 0.4sec for the same polynomial...(I don't know how can this be-I also made sure I don't have anything changed...). It seems that I now agree with your timings (or I even get better ones :)...) Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I think I will not bring the [old version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/276408/1) back, because this version should be just as fast in cases where the minimal `k` is not too small, which is the intended application. (If necessary one can increase `batchsize` a little bit.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
LaunchKernels[];
With[{
  poly = 1 + x + x^2 + x^15 + x^16 + x^17 + x^18
  },
 ParallelTry[
  SelectFirst[
    Range @@ #,
    Function[k, 
      k =!= 0 && PolynomialMod[x^k - 1, poly, Modulus -> 2] === 0
    ],
    $Failed
  ]&,
  Partition[FindDivisions[{1, 10^6, 1}, Length @ Kernels[]], 2, 1]
 ]
]
```

One potential issue though: you're not guaranteed to get the lowest value of `k` this way. But I guess that's a somewhat inherent problem to parallelizing this kind of problem.

Comment: The issue you mention at the end was the reason why I updated my answer from [this version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/276408/1) to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/276408/2).

Comment: I tried running it for this polynomial ```1 + x^7 + x^{10} - x^{11} + x^{13} - x^{14} + x^{15} + x^{16} - x^{17} + x^{18} - x^{20} + x^{21} + x^{24}```. I run your code like this ```With[...]//Timing``` . The first time I have ```FindDivisions[{1, 10^6, 1}...]```. The output is ```{1.5`, 758835}```. The second time I run it with the max limit to ```FindDivisions[{1, 10^7, 1}...]```. The output is ```{1.03125`, 7505568}```. I am not really sure what is going on here...Am I missing anything? Do you get the same outputs?

Comment: Like I said: it will find the first result across different kernels; not necessarily the lowest result. You'd need to use `ParallelMap` to find the lowest value.